# Exporting data from Entry widgets into SQL code

Tags: python, sql, tkinter, sqlite

So I found this really useful piece of code earlier that created entry boxes and when they were created I could edit what was inside of them. The data that was loaded in was taken from an SQL table. Once I have made edits to the entry boxes, I want to submit the data to overwrite the data that had previously been in that sql record, as it it was being edited. The code I found was this:

```
for item in selectedetails:
        entry = Entry(top2)
        entry.insert(0, item)
        entry.pack()
        entries.append(entry)
```

I want it to be able to enter an sql code. I have tried this but it doesn't work. I think I am doing it wrong.

```
def submitedit():
    for entry in entries:
        print(entry.get())



    db = sqlite3.connect('TestFile')
    cursor = db.cursor()

    cursor.execute('''UPDATE Table SET ID=?, Name=?, Desc=? WHERE ID=?''',
    ("?"," ?"," ?").format(entry.get()))
    cursor.close()
    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

I have also tried this:

```
    db = sqlite3.connect('TestFile')
    cursor = db.cursor()

    cursor.execute('''UPDATE Table SET ID=?, Name=?, Desc=? WHERE ID=?''',
    (entry.get())
    cursor.close()
    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
with sqlite3.connect('TestFile') as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    sql = "UPDATE Table  Name=?, Desc=? WHERE ID=?"
    cursor.execute(sql,(Name,Descr))
    db.commit()
```

Note that the order that you put your values in `cursor.execute` line must match up to the order used in sql variable, otherwise the wrong values will be used at the wrong time. Also i have taken out set ID due to that being what you are searching off which im guessing is your primary key, in databases you should not edit the primary key. The primary key should be auto incremented as well.